# Image not visible in email when inserting with <img> tag but visible when using direct link

Tags: php, html, image, .htaccess, email

I have a really basic script that creates an image. Let's just pretend it's on the server example.com and is named test.php

```
$im=imagecreate(150,150);
$white=imagecolorallocate($im,0,0,0);
imagesetpixel($im,1,1,$white);
header("content-type:image/jpg");
imagejpeg($im);
imagedestroy($im);
```

When I now call `http://example.com/test.php` I can see an image. But when I want to send an email and set this as a body

```
<img border='0' src='http://example.com/test.php' width='150' height='150'>
```

However, now I don't see an image. I just see a blank square, that has no source image url. I'm using GMail but it also didn't work in Apple Mail. The mail doesn't land in the spam folder either, so images aren't blocked. There's also no .htaccess blocking the access or something like that.

Any more ideas?

Comment: Have to tried using it in an html page to see if it works? If it is just in emails, its probably a security thing.

Answer (score 0):

There is problem in headers they are case sensitive. content-type is not similiar to Content-Type. And mime type image/jpg is not exists you should use image/jpeg.

```
$im=imagecreate(150,150);
$white=imagecolorallocate($im,0,0,0);
imagesetpixel($im,1,1,$white);
header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
imagejpeg($im);
imagedestroy($im);
```

This should work.